# Content-Disposition: attachment alongside HTML

Tags: php, html, http

I have the following response headers for one of my file download pages:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"
Content-Length: 286269
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/zip
```

Since it takes some time for the zip to assemble, the request for the most time is blank with no information.

Is there a way to display a HTML page before/alongside this file download?

Comment: Don't think so, one workaround would be to create a html which embeds the file download in an iframe, and show a message to the user.

Comment: you can display the user a html page and then start the download with a ajax call, don't really know if it fits your needs...

Comment: At least not easily. Also please note that there is no Content-Transfer-Encoding header field in HTTP.